# Analyzing JS code to grab a cookie at client-side

Tags: javascript, cookies, analysis

I'm new to JS, and I am analyzing a long program code. I cannot understanding this function, except that it is trying to grab a cookie from the client-side. Could anyone point out the functionality here?

```
function get_cookie(a) {
        var b = a + "=";
        var c = "";
        if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
             offset = document.cookie.indexOf(b);
             if (offset != -1) {
                 offset += b.length;
                 end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
                 if (end == -1) {
                     end = document.cookie.length;
                }
                c = unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end));
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function get_cookie(a) {
        var b = a + "="; // Getting argument a and assigning it to var b appending =
        var c = ""; // defining variable c  
        if (document.cookie.length > 0) {  //checking cookie length in browser
             offset = document.cookie.indexOf(b);  // checking b exists or not
             if (offset != -1) { // if b exists 
                 offset += b.length; // getting no of string and assigning it to offset
                 end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset); //checking if ';' is present
                 if (end == -1) { // if ';' is not there in cookie string, 
                     end = document.cookie.length; - // cookie is not set, SO assigning length to the variable end
                }
                c = unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end)); // assigning those values to c
            }
        }
        return c; // returning new cookie.
    }
```

Comment: `if (offset != -1)` <- doesn't this mean if b _does_ exist?

Comment: offset has the value 1 if 'a=' is present in cookie or -1 if it is not present. So its checking b is there or not? . So it make sense.

Comment: can you give proper definition for the above condition then?

Comment: Yes. So `offset != -1` will evaluate to true if `b` is found.